# How to compute the derivative of this matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

The matrix $\mathbf{A}(c)$ with the dimension $M \times N$, $c$ is a scalar variable. The matrix $\mathbf{d}$ is a constant matrix with the dimension $M \times 1$. If the formula $\frac{d\mathbf{A}(c)}{dc}$ has been known, I need to compute the derivative of $f(c)$
$$f(c) = \mathbf{A}(c)\Big( \mathbf{A}^T(c)\mathbf{A}(c) \Big)^{-1}\mathbf{A}^T(c)\mathbf{d}$$

Is there an expression $\frac{df}{dc}$ by $\frac{d\mathbf{A}(c)}{dc}$

Comment: If $\operatorname{inv} (S) = S^{-1}$ (for square, invertible $S$), then $D \operatorname{inv} (S)H = - S^{-1}HS^{-1}$. So, using the chain & product rule you can certainly compute ${df(c) \over dc}$, but it is messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) we see that the derivative of an inverse is
$$\frac{\partial Y^{-1}}{\partial c} = -Y^{-1}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial c}Y^{-1}$$
We can use that to get
$$\frac{d(A^TA)^{-1}}{dc} = -(A^TA)^{-1}(\frac{d(A^TA)}{dc})(A^TA)^{-1}$$
but we can just use the product rule on that to get:
$$\frac{d(A^TA)^{-1}}{dc} = -(A^TA)^{-1}(\frac{dA^T}{dc}A + A^T\frac{dA}{dc})(A^TA)^{-1}$$
Now we want to use the product rule again on the whole sequence to get:
\begin{align*}
f'(c) &= \frac{dA}{dc}(A^TA)^{-1}A^Td + A\frac{d(A^TA)^{-1}}{dc}A^Td + A(A^TA)^{-1}\frac{dA}{dc}d + 0
\end{align*}
Where the last term is zero because $d$ is a constant. Now we can plug in the earlier term and we get what I believe to be the most simplified form possible:

\begin{align*}
f'(c) &= \frac{dA}{dc}(A^TA)^{-1}A^Td - A(A^TA)^{-1}(\frac{dA^T}{dc}A + A^T\frac{dA}{dc})(A^TA)^{-1}A^Td + A(A^TA)^{-1}\frac{dA}{dc}d
\end{align*}
Since A just depends on c, let's replace the derivatives with just primes and we get something that looks prettier:
\begin{align*}
f'(c) &= A'(A^TA)^{-1}A^Td - A(A^TA)^{-1}({A'}^TA + A^TA')(A^TA)^{-1}A^Td + A(A^TA)^{-1}A'd
\end{align*}

Comment: Still not pretty, but I believe this is the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete derivation, but if you take PhysicsKid's answer and define
$$\eqalign{
\def\sym#1{\operatorname{sym}\left(#1\right)}
&\sym{X} = \tfrac12\left(X+X^T\right)
 \qquad&\big({\rm symmetric\;part\;of\;}X\big) \\
&A^+ = \left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T
 \qquad&\big({\rm pseudo\;inverse\;of\;}A\big) \\
&\dot A = \frac{dA}{dc}
 \qquad&\big({\rm dot\;notation\;for\;derivatives}\big) \\
&H = AA^+ = H^T
 \qquad&\big({\rm Hat\;matrix\;of\;}A\big) \\
&\dot H = 2\,\sym{(I-H)\dot AA^+}
 \qquad&\big(\ldots{\rm its\;derivative}\big) \\
&f = Hd
 \qquad&\big({\rm your\;function}\big) \\
}$$
Then the desired derivative can be written more concisely as
$$\eqalign{
{\dot f=\dot Hd}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\qquad\quad
\\
}$$
**NB**:$\,$ You can find derivations of the formula for $\dot H$ in some statistics textbooks such as 
Harville's$\,$ *Matrix Algebra from a Statisticians's Perspective*
$\,$but they are not as direct as PhysicsKid's answer.